# How to query PostgrSQL JSONB array with Any with Dapper

Tags: postgresql, dapper, jsonb, postgresql-json

I'm trying to get a query like the following done with Dapper. Documentation around json is a bit slim though and I couldn't figure it out so far.

Basically I need to run a query similar to this one.

```
select * from table
WHERE  jsonbfield @> ANY (ARRAY ['[{"property1": "value1", "property2":"value2"}]', '[{"property1": "value3", "property2": "value4"}]']::jsonb[]);
```

How can I pass this through a parameter?

Here some more details what I've tried so far.
The field contains aggregated data like this as jsonb.

```
Similar to this
[{
    "property1": "value1",
    "property2": "value2,
},
{
    "property1": "value3",
    "property2": "value4,
}]
```

As mentioned in comments, the sql query is actually working and returning what I need. However, I'm not able so far to pass the data as a parameter. If I include it directly in the query it's working fine. But I would prefer to use parameters instead.

So this is working.

```
"select * from table where jsonbfield @> ANY (ARRAY['[{\"property1\": \"value1\"}]']::jsonb[])"
```

This ain't

```
var parameter = "'[{\"property1\": \"value1\"}]'";
"select * from table where jsonbfield @> ANY (ARRAY[@parameter]::jsonb[])"
```

Comment: Just pass `'[{"property1": "value1", "property2":"value2"}]', '[{"property1": "value3", "property2": "value4"}]'` as string parameter

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect to match?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I guess I'm missing some detail. Tried passing like this '[{"property1":"value1"}]'. And pass the parameter like this where jsonbfield @> ANY (ARRAY[@Parameter]::jsonb[])

Comment: @Schwern I have a field that contains a jsonb array of several properties. And I try to lookup rows that match any given value.

Comment: @treze *Exactly match* or *contain*? An example of your data and expected result would help clear things up.

Comment: @treze If this is a Dapper issue, please show us your Dapper code and the error you're getting.

Comment: @treze What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Or just no results?

Comment: @Schwern Getting an error

Comment: @treze And the error is...?

Comment: @Schwern Sorry, it throws an exception like this
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 22P02: invalid input syntax for type json

Comment: @treze Like in my updated answer and Lukasz's first comment, it's the extra quotes.

Comment: Indeed it's the extra quotes. Additionally the parameter needs to be a list of strings, not just a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Dapper, but the problem is likely the inclusion of quotes around the parameter. Most ORMs will do their own quoting of bind parameters. The extra quotes would be taken literally.

```
var parameter = "[{\"property1\": \"value1\"}]";
```

Given you have an ORM with a query builder, it might be simpler to use `.OrWhere` than to build a Postgres array of jsonb objects. They should perform equivalently.

```
var builder = new SqlBuilder();
var sql = builder.AddTemplate("select * from foo");
builder.OrWhere("jsonb @> @a::jsonb", new { a = '[{"property1": "value1", "property2": "value2"}]' });
builder.OrWhere("jsonb @> @a::jsonb", new { a = '[{"property1": "value3", "property2": "value4"}]' });
```

And, of course, you can do that in a loop.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding. The query itself is actually working. I'm just not able to run it form dapper (ORM). It ends up in some kind of malformed json and it fails.
See also here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130699/postgresql-json-query-array-against-multiple-values

Comment: @treze Ok, how about that?